# Doctrine2 Native Query ManyToMany

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've read the Doctrine2 documentation about native sql queries.
It doesn't talk about entities joined by a ManyToMany relation.
I didn't figure how to handle that, any idea or example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to manually add the join table into the sql.  Extending the example in chpt 14 of the Doctrine manual:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('User', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'name', 'name');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Address' , 'a', 'u', 'address');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'address_id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'street', 'street');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'city', 'city');

$sql = 'SELECT u.id, u.name, a.id AS address_id, a.street, a.city FROM users u ' .
       'INNER JOIN address__user j ON u.id = j.user '.
       'INNER JOIN address a ON a.id = j.address '.
       'WHERE u.name = ?';
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, 'romanb');

$users = $query->getResult();
```

This example assumes your join table has fields address and user for its keys.

Comment: @Lighthart there is an issue in your query. you are using 'j' alias for multiple tables. why are you using 'AND' between joins ?

Comment: Fixed. Since this is more than a year old, I presume the OP simple corrected the analog in his own code.